# Quanto/Compo adjustments - Product of two geometric brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let's say I have two processes
$X_t =X_0 \exp((a-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2)t +\sigma_X dW_t^1)$ and $Y_t=Y_0 \exp((b-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_Y^2)t +\sigma_Y dW_t^2)$ and I then multiply them together (like converting a foreign asset into domestic currency). I arrive at

$X_tY_t = X_0Y_0 \exp((a+b-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_Y^2)t +\sigma_X dW_t^1+\sigma_Y dW_t^2)$

If I then assume the $W_t$ have a correlation of $\rho$, how would I obtain the expectation of $X_tY_t$. The thing that is troubling me is because I have 2 Brownian motions and I'm not sure how to compute from there.

**Edit:**
I would like to make this question a little bit more general. What would I do if I wanted to compute $E[X_t Y_s]$, where say $s < t$. So something to do with independent increments would play a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact that 
$$ \sigma_X W_t^1 + \sigma_Y W_t^2 = \sqrt{ \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y } W_t $$
holds in probability assuming that $W_t^1$ and $W_t^2$ are 2 correlated Brownian motions with
$$ d\langle W_t^1, W_t^2 \rangle_t = \rho dt $$
and $W_t$ is a new standard Brownian motion defined over the same probability space.

Simply put, just replace your sum of two correlated Gaussians (LHS above) by a single Gaussian (RHS above) exhibitting the exact same statistical properties (for a Gaussian identical mean/variance is enough). Doing so, you can now use the formulas you are accustomed to.

Applying this shows
$$ X_t Y_t = X_0Y_0 \exp((a+b-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_Y^2)t +\sqrt{ \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y } W_t) $$
is lognormally distributed with mean 
$$ \mu = \ln(X_0Y_0)+(a+b-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_Y^2)t $$
and variance
$$ \sigma^2 = (\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y)t $$

hence applying the usual formula for the mean of a lognormally distributed variable
$$ E[X_t Y_t] = e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2} $$
is a function of $\rho$.

---

**[Edit]**

I think you are completely mixing up two different problems (here two different probability measures).

I understand from your comment that you define the dynamics of the FOR/DOM instantaneous exchange rate $X_t$ (i.e. $X_t = x$ meaning that, at time $t$, 1 unit of foreign currency = x units of domestic currency) under the **foreign risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}^f$** (or rather the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{Q}^f)$ along with the price process of an equity underlying denominated in the foreign currency.

In that case, under the **domestic risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}^d$** (or rather the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{Q}^d)$), one should have, by absence of arbitrage opportunities and assuming market completeness:
$$ \frac{Y_t X_t}{B_t^d} \text{ is a } \mathbb{Q}^d \text{- martingale} $$

with $B^d_t$ representing the time-$t$ value of a risk-free money market account in the domestic economy in which 1 unit of currency has been invested at $t=0$. Using the martingale property it then entails that:
$$ \frac{Y_0 X_0}{B_0^d} = Y_0 X_0 = E^{\mathbb{Q}^d} \left[ \frac{Y_t X_t}{B_t^d} \vert \mathcal{F}_0 \right] $$
and further assuming deterministic rates:
$$ E ^{\mathbb{Q}^d} \left[ X_t Y_t \vert \mathcal{F}_0 \right] = e^{-r_d t}  X_0 Y_0 $$
which is independent of $\rho$.

This is known as a **compo** adjustment in deriatives lingo.

That being said, **under the measure $\mathbb{Q}^f$** where you have originally defined $X_t$ and $Y_t$, the **expectation $E^{\mathbb{Q}^f} [ Y_t X_t ]$ does dependent on $\rho$ as hinted above**.

More info on the quanto/compo change of measure technique [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25797/girsanov-theorem-for-quanto-compo-adjustment)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I guess I might be having trouble applying this to my problem. My problem has $X_t =X_0\exp((r_d-r_f-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2)t+\sigma_X W_t^1)$ and $Y_t =Y_0\exp((r_f-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_Y^2)t+\sigma_Y W_t^2)$. What would be the expectation of $X_tY_t$ because my answer involves $\rho$, when I know for certain that it should not.

Comment: @Jim, you are actually mixing up two different problems, please see my edits

Comment: The relationship you are trying to show is only true for a specific situation known as compo adjustment (has to do with quanto changes of measures), I would advise to change the title of your question to reflect that, for it is an interesting question, not asked in the right way.

Comment: Great explanation of my two minds. Would you be able to show how you arrive at the expectation for the compo adjustment (as you call it). Do I need to use Girsanov?

Comment: Do you agree that if you manage to show that $Y_t X_t / B_t^d$ is a $\mathbb{Q}^d$-martingale then you are done?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. But how would one go from the $Q^f$ measure to the $Q^d$ measure.

Comment: Well this martingale property is simply a consequence of the **fundamental theorems of asset pricing** as some call them: in the absence of arbitrage opportunities (+ complete market) there exists a unique **risk-neutral** measure in which all tradable asset prices are martingales when the risk-free money market account is used as numéraire. Here, we look at the domestic economy. The foreign asset $Y_t$ is not directly tradable in that economy (since denominated in foreign currency units), so you first need to convert $Y_t$ to domestic  units $Y_t X_t$ before applying the numéraire $B^d_t$

Comment: Ah yes, you do need Girnasov in that case, I will edit my post give me 2 secs.

Comment: @Jim, hope this clears everything.

Comment: Would you be able to quickly show the Girsanov transformation. I've never worked with these measures before so it's a little confusing for me. Other than that, this has been excellent

Comment: @Jim Sorry but this has already gone too far out of topic, IMO your original question has already been answered. It is better to keep the 1 question/1 answer format, this is not a forum! So I would be pleased to help you; but just ask a new question publicly.

Comment: I have added in an edit to try and generalise this result. Would you be able to help with that.

Comment: @Jim, I'm sure everyone here would be glad to help. But as we already discussed, the Stack Exchange format is 1 question / 1 answer. So you better ask this in a new, separate, question

Comment: Oh I thought that since it was just a generalisation, I wouldn't need a new question.